# Parsing Json in Android and set it in a ListView

Tags: java, android, json

In my android project, I have the string `text` which got the following data:

```
[
  {
  "admin": true,
  "created_at": "2012-10-16T07:26:49Z",
  "email": "asdf@gmail.com",
  "id": 28,
  "language": "fr",
  "name": "Marc",
  "profile_pic_content_type": null,
  "profile_pic_file_name": null,
  "profile_pic_file_size": null,
  "profile_pic_updated_at": null,
  "provider": null
  },
  {
  "admin": false,
  "created_at": "2013-04-02T18:47:36Z",
  "email": "asdf2@gmail.com",
  "id": 263,
  "language": "en",
  "name": "Marcus",
  "profile_pic_content_type": null,
  "profile_pic_file_name": null,
  "profile_pic_file_size": null,
  "profile_pic_updated_at": null,
  "provider": null
  }
]
```

I converted it into a json object thanks to this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(text);
```

I want to parse that Json object, and setting it inside a ListView, but even with the [official documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) I can't succeed in doing so.

After parsing, I want to keep only the first part of the array, and delete every field excepting the email, language and name, to get this in the end:

```
[
  {
  "email": "asdf@gmail.com",
  "language": "fr",
  "name": "Marc"
  }
]
```

Comment: Converting it inside a json object, trying to parse it before converting it as a json object as a string, but still no success

Comment: post the code.. relevant snippet

Comment: You will laugh at me.
`Log.e("retrieve2",text.toCharArray()[0]);`

Comment: is text.toCharArray()[0] your parsing code?

Comment: I'm trying here to parse the string into an array, and getting the first part of the array out of it. And yeah, Log is for debugging...

Comment: If a JSON string starts with square brackets, [, then you need to use a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. If it starts with curly brackets, {, you use a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Edit your question. Post the code. Explain better your issue. In what you succeed and in what you have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a `JSONArray` - the [ ] - that contains two separate `JSONObject`. The way you extract values from this structure is simply to go piece by piece, first getting the nested objects from the array and then extracting their internal values. You can then repackage it as you wish.  For example:

```
int numObject = jsonArray.length();
JSONArray repackArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0; i < numObject; i++){
    JSONObject nested = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);

    //get values you need
    String email = nested.getString("email");
    String language = nested.getString("language");
    String name = nested.getString("name");

    //add values to new object
    JSONObject repack = new JSONObject();
    repack.put("email", email);
    repack.put("language", language);
    repack.name("name", name);

    //add to new array 
    repackArray.put(repack);
 }
```

Alternatively if put doesn't work for you, you can always create your own String in JSON format and then simply create a new `JSONObject` using that string as an argument in the constructor. I assumed you were working with a `JSONArray` in the above example. If you're starting with a `JSONObject` the process is the same. Just get the `JSONArray` out of the object first before unpacking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I implemented it but I got this:
`The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)` for the "nested.getString" three lines.
It expects an index, not a string. Should I define the line number manually?

Comment: Get string [does not require an index](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). You got that error because are trying to get a string value from a `JSONArray`. You can only get those string values from the `JSONObject` - the part enclosed in {}. I based that code on the text you provided above. If the actual JSON is a different format - say that text wrapped in another `JSONObject` you need to extract that array first or convert to a `JSONArray` using toJSONArray before it will work.